# Restriction of a linear application (a matrix) to two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $Z=\{(x_1,x_2): x_1 = x_2 \}$ and $S= \{ (y_1,y_2): y_2=0\}$ and consider the linear application defined by
$$M = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Compute $M_{ZS}$, i.e. the restriction of $M$ operating from $Z$ to $S$.

---

My attempt:
In class we have said that in order to define $M_{ZS}$ one has to compute $$M_{ZS} = \pi_S M E_Z$$

where $E_Z$ is the extension operator. Given a subspace $Z \subset \mathbb{R}^r$, it associates to any $z \in Z$, the same element, but seen as an element of $\mathbb{R}^r$.

While $\pi_S= E_S^t$, i.e. the transpose of the extension operator associated to $S$.

Now, $Z$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and it's spanned by $(1,1)^T$. Also $S$ is a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, spanned by $e_1$.
So the application $E_Z: Z \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $(x,x) \mapsto (x,x)$ has matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1  \end{bmatrix}$

and $E_S$ has matrix
$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}$ so that $\pi_s=E_S^t = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &0  \end{bmatrix}^T$

If you now perform $\pi_S M E_Z$ you find **just the number $0$**. **What am I missing?** Is this possible?

Comment: in your definition of $S$ you seem to have a typo. Should it be $S=\{(y_1,y_2):\,\,y_1=0\}$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes, I've just fixed this

Comment: you still have $y_2=0$. Shouldn't it be $y_1=0$?

Comment: Ups no no, $y_2$ is the correct one. I thought you were referring to the fact I wrote $x$s instead of $y$s @peek-a-boo

Comment: @peek-a-boo Is this the reason why I found that $M_{ZS}$ is identically $0$?

Comment: The reason I asked these questions is that $M$ maps $Z$ into $S_1=\{(y_1,y_2)\,:\,y_1=0\}$. Not into the subspace $S$ you defined. So, you cannot restrict $M$ to get a linear map $Z\to S$.

Comment: Indeed I think that my result is then correct: the restriction produces the $0$ vector...

Answer (score 1):

This is the right answer.  For all $z \in Z$, $\pi_S M z = 0$.

Using slightly different notation, let $z \in Z$.  Then there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $z = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha  \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}$.  So
$$
    \pi_S Mz = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} \alpha  \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Wow... that seems strange to me: the professor said that its kernel is $\{(x_1,x_2): x_1=x_2\}$. Isn't this wrong? @MatthweLeingang

Comment: Kernel of what?  The kernel of $M$ is $\{0\}$ because $M$ is invertible.  The kernel of $\pi_S$ is $\{x_1 = 0\}$.  But the calculation above proves that the kernel of $\pi_S \mathrel{\circ} M$ is $Z$.

Comment: I was referring to the kernel of $M_{ZS}$. I can't understand why my professor said that the kernel of $M_{ZS}$ is $Z$.  @MatthewLeingang

Comment: The Kernel of $M_{ZS}$ is $Z$, because $\operatorname{Im}(M_{ZS})=\{0\}$, so $\operatorname{Ker}(M_{ZS})=M_{ZS}^{-1}(\{0\})=\operatorname{Dom}(M_{ZS})=Z$

Comment: The professor said that because it's true.  The kernel of a linear transformation is the subspace of vectors sent to zero by that transformation.  $M_{ZS}$ is a linear transformation from $Z$ to $S$, and every vector in $Z$ is sent to zero by $M_{ZS}$.  Therefore the kernel of $M_{ZS}$ is all of $Z$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks, I need just one last thing before accepting the answer: why did you define $\pi_S$ in that way? In my attempt it was the row vector $[1 \quad 0]$, but you have a 2 by 2 matrix.

Comment: @bobinthebox The matrix of a linear transformation depends on the ambient spaces and bases for the domain and codomain.  I'm thinking of $S$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, spanned by $(1,0)^T$, and $\pi_S$ as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose image is $S$.  You're thinking of it as a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $S$, and using a basis for $S$ to represent it as a matrix.